# Class sendo adicionada em apenas um elemento do laço de repetição (PHP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, while

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema há um tempinho e nele estava implementando a *LAZY LOAD*, aquela famosa técnica de carregamento de imagens que só são carregadas quando o usuário rolar a página até onde elas estão.

Optei pela *API Intersection Observer*, só que algumas versões do *IE* não a suportam; pensando nisso, decidi criar uma verificação para aparecer uma mensagem caso o navegador não suporte, até aqui tudo bem, consegui com o seguinte código abaixo:

```
if ("IntersectionObserver" in window === false){
    $("#image-load").append("<p class='p_um no-img'>Seu navegador não 
suporta a API, atualize a versão ou tente acessar com outro. </p>");
}
```

Este código cria uma nova *div* dentro do *container #image-load* com a mensagem que queria (este *container #image-load* está em um laço de repetição, cada imagens que tenho no *WHILE* também saem com esse *container* — Código abaixo). O problema é que as minhas imagens estão em um Laço de repetição no *PHP* e o código está apenas funcionando no primeiro elemento do *WHILE*.

Quebrei a cabeça e não consegui nada além. Segue abaixo a maneira que está sendo impressa o *while* no *HTML*.

```
<div class="cover-det" id="image-load">
     <img data-src="img-1.jpg">
     <p class='p_um no-img'>Seu navegador não suporta a API, atualize a versão ou tente acessar com outro.    
     </p>
</div>

<div class="cover-det" id="image-load">
     <img data-src="img-2.jpg">
</div>

<div class="cover-det" id="image-load">
     <img data-src="img-3.jpg">
</div>
```

E assim vai...

A minha pergunta é a seguinte: Como fazer essa mensagem ser reproduzida em todas as imagens desse meu *while* no *PHP*?

Comment: O erro está em utilizar o mesmo `id` para vários elementos. Substitua `$("#image-load").append(...)` por `$("div.cover-det").append(...)`

Comment: Funcionando perfeitamente! Olha esse detalhe da utilização de repetições de id tinha me fugido kkk, enfim MUITO OBRIGADO!